# nginx load balancing without proxying trafic

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

I want to use nginx to load balance http traffic, but without proxying the traffic.

Like this user > lb > server > user

And not a standard proxy like

user > lb > server > lb > user

Is this possible or maybe I should look at another application?

Comment: What you mean by the `server > user` part? Typically it is `user > lb > multiple servers sharing the load`.

Comment: I meant that the backend server will send traffic directly to the user, and not going back to the lb. That onces the load balancer redirect the user, the user will talk directly to the server

Comment: Could a simple *Round Robin DNS* be the solution you are looking for?

Comment: I'm already using round robin dns with cloudflare but the traffic is not really balanced at all, like right now i have servers with 0 load and one with 4

Comment: round Robin does not work well as I have my knowledge about. a load balance is the most effective way to solve this.

Comment: Yes i want to load balance but not proxy the traffic after the redirect

Comment: What you seem to describe is like [Linux Virtual Server](http://www.linuxvirtualserver.org/) implemented in so called *Direct Routing* mode; however, I can't get where Nginx can help here. It is nowhere listed in LVS software stack.

Comment: As @NikitaKipriyanov already mentioned ; that is not something nginx supports. It is possible though and useful in some use cases. For example HAproxy offers that functionality as [***direct return***](https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/aloha/latest/load-balancing/direct-server-return/) which is conceptually similar to LVS direct routing. Note that it requires more custimisation in the back-end servers and possibly your network infrastructure than the conventional reverse proxy.

Comment: @HBruijn is this feature available only in a commercial paid version of HAproxy?

Comment: seems like direct return is exactly what I need... but seems a bit difficult to setup